# I want to change the width of the item while dragging from the sortable lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I need to change the width of the item while dragging from the sortable lists.

Here am using below jquery

```
$(function() {
    $( ".dropfalse" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".dropfalse",
            revert: true,           
            tolerance: 'pointer'    
        }).disableSelection();
    $('#sortable1 li').draggable({
        connectToSortable: ".dropfalse",
        helper: "clone",
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while dragging you can modify the CSS using $("selector").css("property","value");

Comment: i have used that but placeholder changed the width:


  $( ".dropfalse" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".dropfalse",
    revert: true,   
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    start: function(event, ui) { 
     $("#sortable2 li").css("width","150px");
     $("#sortable3 li").css("width","150px");
    
     },
    stop: function(event, ui) { 
     $("#sortable2 li").css("width","100%");
     $("#sortable3 li").css("width","100%");    
     }

   }).disableSelection();

Comment: if possible, can you create a JsFiddle for this? It would be more helpful. Or, you can check the id of the element you want to resize and use that id as selector.